# Sorting textfile with rows of [word number] numerically

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a .txt file that consists of:

```
Aa 6
Bb 3
Aa Aa 2
Bb Bb 10
```

I need to sort it so the result is:

```
Bb Bb 10
Aa 6
Bb 3
Aa Aa 2
```

This only gives the alphabetical order:c

```
cat .txt | sort -n
```

Can you help here? Kind regards Anders

Comment: What are your sorting criteria?

Comment: Related: [How to numerical sort by last column?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10528/380915)

Comment: Thank you for answering! The problem is that the sorting has to be done in both second and third column. Another way to get around this problem: how to make the output of the input sorted in third column? Then I can solve the by the third column afterwards